# Subsetting and whole dataset shiny R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, shiny

I am using shiny and want to plot some things using only a certain subset and the whole dataset.
Users can choose whether to plot the whole dataset or only a subset using selectInput.

So far I have this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput(inputId = "select", label = "Choose subset of analysis", choices = levels(df$c), selected = "groupA"),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)

server <- ({
datasetInput <- reactive({
    req(input$select)
    a <- subset(df, Haircolor %>% in levels(df$c))
    return(a)
  })

output$summary<- summary(datasetInput)
})
```

Subsetting the different levels of df$c works, but what can I do if do not want to subset, but include all observations in the analysis?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you provide `dput(df)` to facilitate testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code has several problems. Since we do not know the original data, I show an example with the `iris` dataset. It should be easily adaptable to your problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

myiris <- mutate(iris, Species = as.factor(Species))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput(inputId = "select",
                  label = "Choose subset of analysis",
                  choices = c("all", levels(myiris$Species)),
                  selected = "all"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    ),
  
    server = function(input, output) {
    
    datasetInput <- reactive({
    req(input$select)
    filter(myiris, input$select == "all" | Species == input$select)
    # alternatively `subset` works as well:
    # subset(myiris, input$select == "all" | Species == input$select)
    })

    output$summary <- renderText(summary(datasetInput()))
  })
```

**Why does `filter(myiris, input$select == "all" | Species == input$select)` work?**

`filter` and also `subset` take an expression as second argument. It is important that

1. this can be *any* logical expression. The expression does not necessarily need to refer to a column name.
2. the expression will be recylced if it does not match the number of rows of the `data.frame`. Notice that `subset` and `filter` have different recycling rules. However, both will recycle an expresison of `length == 1` to the number of rows of the `data.frame`.
3. The expression may contain boolean operators (`&`, `|` etc.)

With this in mind we can construct the expression:
`input$select == "all" | Species == input$select`

Since `input$select == "all"` is of `length == 1` it will be recycled to match the number of elements in `Species == input$select` which is the number of rows of the `data.frame`.

Since we use an OR operator `|`, the expression will be `TRUE` for every row when `all` is selected. If `all` is not selected, the expression  `Species == input$select` will be `TRUE` for all rows that match the selected `input$select`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! Can you please help me understand the code: How does R know to combine all of the levels when "all" is selected? How does the filter work?

Comment: @Phil.He: I added an explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "select", label = "Choose subset of analysis", choices = c("All", unique(df$c)), selected = "groupA"),
  uiOutput("summary")
)

server <- ({
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    req(input$select)
    if (input$select=="All") { a <- df
    }else a <- subset(df, Haircolor %in% input$select)
    return(a)
  })
  
  output$summary<- renderUI({summary(datasetInput())})
})
```

Comment: Hi, sir, could you give me some advice for my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103629/how-to-output-two-grid-plotsgrid-draw-togather-and-download-them-in-shinyapp?noredirect=1#comment118613010_67103629